# vim-supertab no results behavior

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

I would like for `vim-supertab` to revert to the normal behavior of <kbd>Tab</kbd> if the autocomplete command returns no results.  This is especially useful as I often find myself hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the end of strings that are already complete.

How can I modify my `.vimrc` to acheive this behavior?

Comment: Super User is not an issue tracker. Please suggest that to the plugin's author, or even better send him a patch.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an enhancement in a plugin.

Comment: I am asking how to do this given the current plugin, not offering a patch or making a feature request.  If the feature is unavailable, then of course I should make a feature request at the plugin's issue tracker, however vim is certainly configurable enough that this can be done now without patching the plugin.  I'll make this clearer in the question.